# Natively written packet sniffer / inspector for OS X

Tags: network, software, security

I am looking for a packet sniffer / inspector which runs natively on OS X (Cocoa) and not with some sort of compatibility layer like X.

Ideally I am looking for an application with the following qualities:

- native (Cocoa) interface
- ability to inspect packet data
- inspect packet data as XML, or RAW formats
- free

Comment: "Decent" is fairly subjective; are there specific features you require of your packet sniffing program?

Comment: why you didn't use wireshark on mac?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: because its not native. I have updated my question to be more specific btw.

Comment: try tcpdump. :) 1. Free (already in you Mac), has native Cocoa (read Terminal.app) interface :), can inspect packet data and really VERY robust, can filter by any criteria, can save packet data, etc. `man tcpdump`.

Comment: @jm666: Sounds good, will give it a shot. Very cheeky regarding Terminal.app as a cocoa app :p lol

Answer (score 5):

[Packet Peeper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetpeeper/) is a free, native OS X application for packet sniffing. Not quite as robust as Wireshark (but what is really).

There's also [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/), which appears to have a nifty plugin framework for extending its capabilities, but I've never used it. It's donation-ware.

[KisMAC](http://kismac-ng.org/) may also be of interest. Not so much a sniffer as a wireless stumbling tool. I've used it successfully to tune my wireless network in a congested neighbourhood.

Edit: based on your updated desired features I'd say try Packet Peeper. It fulfills both your requirements.