# Packet sniffer for MacOS Mojave and above

Tags: macos, network, software-recommendation, tcp, wireshark

I'm looking for a packet sniffer app that runs on MacOS in a GUI (I know I can accomplish some functionality with native CLI utilities like `tcpdump`).

Previously I used [Packet Peeper](http://packetpeeper.org/release-notes/), however it doesn't seem to run in MacOS 10.14 Mojave (the application opens and seems to run, but no window appears).

** [Other questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15928/natively-written-packet-sniffer-inspector-for-os-x) have also mentioned PP as the solution, but they're all fairly old.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### 1 - Wireshark

If you have `brew` installed it's trivial to install Wireshark via a Cask.

```
$ brew cask install wireshark
```

This will install both the GUI and CLI versions. The GUI version is called `wireshark` and should show up in Launcher. The CLI version should show up in your `$PATH` as `tshark`.

#### GUI

Invoking the GUI will show you a selection window from where you can select which network interface to analyze. **NOTE:** on my system we'll use `en0`.

[image: ss]

A double click on `en0` and you're in selecting packet data.

[image: ss]

#### CLI

To use the CLI it's about as difficult.

```
$ tshark -i en0 | head
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi: en0'
137     1   0.000000 192.168.1.95 → 172.217.6.42 UDP 65 56557 → 443 Len=23
    2   0.111321 192.168.1.95 → 172.217.5.110 ICMP 70 Echo (ping) request  id=0x4300, seq=39758/20123, ttl=255
    3   0.118526 172.217.6.42 → 192.168.1.95 UDP 70 443 → 56557 Len=20
    4   0.150560  192.168.1.2 → 255.255.255.255 UDP 223 44779 → 7437 Len=173
    5   0.152892 192.168.1.87 → 192.168.1.255 BROWSER 241 Browser Election Request
    6   0.155246 192.168.1.10 → 192.168.1.255 BROWSER 239 Browser Election Request
    7   0.157628 192.168.1.69 → 192.168.1.255 BROWSER 243 Browser Election Request
    8   0.161358 192.168.1.95 → 172.217.5.110 ICMP 70 Echo (ping) request  id=0x4300, seq=40014/20124, ttl=1
    9   0.168584  192.168.1.2 → 192.168.1.95 ICMP 106 Time-to-live exceeded (Time to live exceeded in transit)
   10   0.194384 172.217.5.110 → 192.168.1.95 ICMP 78 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x4300, seq=39758/20123, ttl=47 (request in 2)
280 tshark: An error occurred while printing packets: Broken pipe.
```

**NOTE:** Wireshark has excellent tutorials and guides on line once you're past the install.

### 2 - tcpdump

If you want something even lighter, you can use `tcpdump` to capture all types of traffic, not just TCP.

```
$ tcpdump -i en0 -n | head
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:01:20.630058 IP 192.168.1.95 > 172.217.5.110: ICMP echo request, id 17152, seq 21845, length 36
20:01:20.681163 IP 192.168.1.95 > 172.217.5.110: ICMP echo request, id 17152, seq 22101, length 36
20:01:20.688948 IP 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.95: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 64
20:01:20.728713 IP 172.217.5.110 > 192.168.1.95: ICMP echo reply, id 17152, seq 21845, length 36
20:01:20.732391 IP 192.168.1.95 > 172.217.5.110: ICMP echo request, id 17152, seq 22357, length 36
20:01:20.747365 IP 65.190.128.1 > 192.168.1.95: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 64
20:01:20.783439 IP 192.168.1.95 > 172.217.5.110: ICMP echo request, id 17152, seq 22613, length 36
20:01:20.803827 IP 174.111.103.48 > 192.168.1.95: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
20:01:20.820382 IP 192.168.1.2.44779 > 255.255.255.255.7437: UDP, length 173
20:01:20.834717 IP 192.168.1.95 > 172.217.5.110: ICMP echo request, id 17152, seq 22869, length 36
tcpdump: Unable to write output: Broken pipe
```

#### References

- [Wireshark User’s Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/)
- [tshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)
- [tcpdump Examples — 50 Ways to Isolate Specific Traffic](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/)
- [tcpdump tag from Unix & Linux Stackexchange Site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tcpdump)

Comment: Wireshark really is the STANDARD packet sniffer on any platform

Comment: I have always installed Wireshark from the download page https://www.wireshark.org/#download

Answer (score 3):

You probably are looking for [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of Packet Peeper should run on Mojave, it can be downloaded [here](https://bitbucket.org/choll/packetpeeper/downloads/PacketPeeper_2019-04-06.dmg).

If it doesn't please file a [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/choll/packetpeeper/issues/new) and I'll look into it (I am the developer).

Comment: If you are the developer of Packet Peeper, please edit your answer, or add a comment, for attribution.

Comment: @IconDaemon, yes I am the developer.